# As a PHP developer, is it necessary for me to understand the way serialize() generates the storable representation of a value?

Tags: php, serialization, representation, storable

I'm using **PHP 7.1.12** and I'm trying to understand the functionality of one of the most important built-in functions in PHP `serialize()`

I understood that `serialize()` is used to generate a storable representation of a value which is passed to it.

I think it means `serialize()` converts the received value into some string using its internal functionality. Is this my perception right about `serialize()`?

Consider below code :

```
<?php

$a = [];
$a[] = $a;
echo "\na: ".serialize($a);

$b = [];
$b[] =& $b;
echo "\nb: ".serialize($b);
```

**Output :**

```
a: a:1:{i:0;a:0:{}}
b: a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;R:2;}}
```

In the output I'm not able to understand from where the letters **i, a, R** are coming into the output. Also, I'm not able to understand how this output is formed by `serialize()`

So, my question is; As a PHP developer, is it necessary for me to understand above output or should I directly make use of this output without going into the details of it?

Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Well, the output is a string containing a byte-stream representation. To be able to use it in PHP again, you first have to `unserialize()` it. Have you had a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)?

Comment: @Geshode : That I know very well. My question is not why and how to use serialize() and unserialize(). My question is regarding the necessity of understanding the output serialize() generates.

Comment: So, you are asking, if you should know how exactly the representation is generated?

Comment: i wouldn't call it important, it's usually used by people who don't know how to store data a DB correctly; or use the native data formats. Don't think I have used it all year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is the general explanation of what those characters mean.

**String**

```
s:size:value;
```

**Integer**

```
i:value;
```

**Boolean**

```
b:value; (store '1' or '0')
```

**Null**

```
N;
```

**Array**

```
a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}
```

**Object**

```
O:strlen(object name):object name:object size:{s:strlen(property name):property name:property definition;(repeated per property)}
```

It is not really necessary for us to know, how PHP serializes, but if you are are curious, the above explanation would help to understand that there is some logic to it.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy. Tell me why to serialize() and unserialize() the values? Can't we store them as they are into the database or whatever?

Comment: Ideally you would serialize data for caching purposes. So lets say you got a complex business process, which always returns a certain data and this data does not change much. Ideally in this situation, you would cache the serialized data, for anywhere between 15 mins to a day, depending on your needs. So when the next request comes in, you just unserialize the data, rather than running that complex process again, which will make your page load faster. So it is applicable in few cases.

Comment: Ideally it is not recommended to store the serialized data in the database, but more so on your filesystem, since it is not easy to take apart this serialized data and query it in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

Another feature of PHP’s serialization format is that it will properly preserve references: The important part here is the R:2; element. It means “reference to the second value.
    As objects in PHP exhibit a reference-like behavior serialize also makes sure that the same object occurring twice will really be the same object on unserialization:

```
$b = [];
$b[] =& $b;
echo "\nb: ".serialize($b);

output:b: a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;R:2;}}
```

The whole array is the first value, the first index is the second value, so that’s what is referenced.